# After reinstalling kde-plasma-desktop, I lost render of some icon fonts

Tags: 22.04, kubuntu, xorg, kde, fonts

After a mistake with `aptitude` command's options, I lost my kde plasma DE of my kubuntu 22.04 and the computer boots in the CLI mode just like Ubuntu server, So I had to reinstall the `kde-plasma-desktop` again.
After installation I lost some icon fonts render in some applications.
For example:
1- In Firefox's input fields of websites, While it still works in Google chrome:
[image]

In Chrome:

[image]

Also in Konsole's Oh My Fish, powerline icons does not rendered:

[image]

Everything worked fine before that issue. but I don't know exactly what's the missing.